# Exception Handling About RTMP SERVER

Tags: go, exception, server, publish, rtmp

I am using a goalng Pacakge joy4(https://github.com/nareix/joy4) package as RtmpServer.
I think that Exception handling for duplicate keys is required.
if I use this url for RTMP network stream,   **rtmp://localhost:1935/app/test**
First, Using OBS publish the data to RTMP Server.
Second, Using example/rtmp_publish/main.go, publishing the same url rtmp://localhost:1935/app/test
I think that this is definitly issue. Connection becomes unstable.
There is no Exception Handling about Same Stream Key ("test").
Is there Any Good Idea?

https://github.com/nareix/joy4/blob/master/examples/http_flv_and_rtmp_server/main.go
https://github.com/nareix/joy4/blob/master/format/rtmp/rtmp.go

I tried to conn.Close in HandlePublish Function.
Using map, If there Alreay have same Key(URL), I add conn.Close(),
But It is not solving Problem.

```
server.HandlePublish = func(conn *rtmp.Conn) {
        logger.Info("server.HandlePublish start Call")
        streams, _ := conn.Streams()

        l.Lock()
        // if key(rtmp url exists), conn.close()
        ch, ok := channels[conn.URL.Path]
        if ok {
            logger.Errorf("Already published: %s", conn.URL.Path)
            conn.Close() // add this line. 
            return
        }
        if ch == nil {
            logger.Info("after inside of HandlePublish ch is nil")
            ch = &Channel{}
            ch.que = pubsub.NewQueue()
            ch.que.WriteHeader(streams)
            channels[conn.URL.Path] = ch
        } else {
            ch = nil
        }
        l.Unlock()
        if ch == nil {
            return
        }

        avutil.CopyPackets(ch.que, conn)
        l.Lock()
        delete(channels, conn.URL.Path)
        l.Unlock()
        ch.que.Close()
    }
```

I tried this but this is not solution of solving problem..
Is there any good idea?